# Android - Crash starting an activity from a service

Tags: android, start-activity, affinity, activity-stack

I get the following crash on Firebase crashlytics and I have no idea what I can do to solve it.

It happens very rarely. The scenario is that I start an activity from a service while the app is in the background. Any thoughts?

It happens on Android 11 and I have been granted the draw overlay permission when it happens.

*Android 11 introduced the need for apps to have the draw overlay permission to start activities from a service while they are in the background. I make sure that I have it so that is not the cause of the issue.*

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.android.server.wm.Task.affinity' on a null object reference 


Caused by android.os.RemoteException
Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityInnerLocked(ActivityStack.java:2092) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:1710) at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.resumeFocusedStacksTopActivities(RootWindowContainer.java:2475) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.resumeTargetStackIfNeeded(ActivityStarter.java:3169) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.recycleTask(ActivityStarter.java:2521)
```

Comment: I suppose you start activity not from the background?

Comment: @IgorBykov it happens while the app is in the background. But the app is also in the background all the other 99.99% of the times which don't crash.